# Loop to save vertices in openGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glut

I have a grid with tetragons and i want to save all the vertices in an array. I wrote ths code:

```
int counter=0;
int i = 0;
for(i=0; i<=600; i+=40){
    verticePosition[counter] = i;
    verticePosition[counter+1] = i;
    verticePosition[counter+2] = i+40;
    verticePosition[counter+3] = i;
    verticePosition[counter+4] = i;
    verticePosition[counter+5] = i+40;
    verticePosition[counter+6] = i+40;
    verticePosition[counter+7] = i+40;
    counter += 8;
}
```

I want to save four-four vertices in the table and then i call a function to fill every tetragon with a different color but im getting an error in this for loop:

```
prog.c:13:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘for’
 for(xpos=0; xpox<=600; xpos+=40){
 ^
```

and also another error:

```
prog.c:13:17: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘<=’ token
 for(xpos=0; xpox<=600; xpos+=40){
             ^
```

I cant find what is wrong with my loop.

Comment: You should provide more code around the failing code because the problem may come from the previous lines of code. BTW, in the second for, xpox should be xpos?

Comment: i changed all the xpos with i but im getting the same errors

Comment: dimitris, please show us more code around prog.c so that we can help you.

Comment: The variables in the code given do not match those in the errors. Post the actual code causing the error.

Comment: @dimitrisdimas1313 Are you, by any chance, having all this code outside a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `xpos` is used but not declared, you must declare and initialize it:

```
for (int xpos = 0; xpos <= 600;  xpos += 40) {
```

Or declare it before the loop:

```
int xpos;
for (xpos = 0; xpos <= 600;  xpos += 40) {
```